# Javascript getJson exception handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a simple javascript that fetches some JSON data from a webserver every 400ms  and update various div's with the content - its working fine on 99 out of 100% calls.
But the webserver holding the json will occasionally not respond, be unavaileble or the like. If it happens simultainously with a page load I get a "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php" and have to reload the page. 
If the page is loaded before a drop out from the json server the div's are just not updated, but will be once the server responds again.

I need to find a way to avoid the "failed to open stream: HTTP request fai..." messages on the user interface (a php page) and at any time update a div with "Connection OK" or "Connection down".

I have been looking at exceptionhandling for getJSON, but cant find the right method.

My script:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });  
     setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://myurl.com/test/jsonreplica.php', function(data) {
        data_loaded=data; 
        var len_data_loaded = data_loaded['Devices'].length;
        var len_data_current = data_current['Devices'].length;


// UPDATE ALL MY DIV's

}  
        });

    }, 400);

</script>
```

Comment: Read the docs. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

All the jQuery AJAX functions return a `jqXHR` promise, which has methods like `.done()` and `.error()`. So you can write:

```
$.getJSON('URL', function(data) {
    // Do stuff
}).error(function() {
    // Deal with error
});
```